# Grouping and resorting values in PHP array using substrings

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, grouping

I have an array sorted alphabetically with string values like this: "Los Angeles, California"; "Osaka, Japan"; "San Diego, California"; "Tokyo, Japan"; etc.  I need to output html that orders and groups the items alphabetically by the substring after the comma, then alpha by the substring before the comma.  Ideally what I would get a set of nested unordered lists:

California

```
Los Angeles

San Diego
```

Japan

```
Osaka

Tokyo
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$source_array = array(...);    // your array
$result_array = array();
foreach ($source_array as $item) {
   list($city, $state) = explode(',', $item);
   $state = trim($state);
   $result_array[$state][] = $city;
}
// then do some sort, ksort for example
ksort($result_array);
```